# Redirect back to page I entered from after logging in

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

```
public function login()
{
$login = EmployeeLogin::whereEmail(request()->email_id)->first();
if ($login) {

 if($login->active == 1){
     if (Auth::guard('employer')->attempt(['email' => request()->email_id, 'password' => request()->pwd]))
     {
        Auth::guard('employer')->user(); 
        return redirect()->intended('/');       
     }
     else{
        return redirect()->route('employer.auth')->with('message','Incorrect Email id or Password');
     }}}}
```

How to redirect back to page I entered from after logging in?

We have already tried using

- `redirect()->back()`
- `return Redirect::route('dashboard');` and
- with return `Redirect::intended('dashboard');`

I'm using laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Use [intended()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users) method

```
return redirect()->intended('/');
```

From docs

> The `intended` method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Comment: where we have to give  return redirect()->intended('/');

Comment: in your login function after login is completed

Comment: return redirect()->intended('/')- this is redirecting to home page.

Comment: i will tell you the scenario. For example we have created a auth middle ware and implemented to some of pages. Now if i am trying to access those private pages, its prompting to login page. After login i want to go to private page

Comment: @Rashmi that's what this is intended for, are you using laravel default auth?? please share your login function

Comment: Yes we are using default auth

Comment: find this method and change to this `private function sendLoginResponse(Login $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    }`

Comment: public function login()
  {
    $login = EmployeeLogin::whereEmail(request()->email_id)->first();
    if ($login) {
       
     if($login->active == 1){
         if (Auth::guard('employer')->attempt(['email' => request()->email_id, 'password' => request()->pwd]))
         {
            Auth::guard('employer')->user(); 
            return redirect()->intended('/');       
         }
         else{
            return redirect()->route('employer.auth')->with('message','Incorrect Email id or Password');
         }
}
}
}

Comment: @Rashmi please add this in your question, you should have add this way before

Comment: ohh sorry. Thanks. I will add

Comment: your login function is fine, it seems your middleware is redirecting to `/` after login, not your redirect code

Comment: now where should I change, so that it will redirect to the private page instead  /.and this is my function- protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use `Redirect::to()`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

return Redirect::to('dashboard');
```

And in **routes.php**

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'Controller@method')->name('dashboard');
```